# A sum of a closed subspace and a closed one-dimensional space is closed

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, direct-sum

I'm losing my mind over this question.
For $H$ a Hilbert space, $A,B$ closed subspaces, and $B$ is of dimension $1$, I want to prove that $A+B$ is also closed.

I'm looking for a straightforward proof, with minimum use of high theorems (without Hahn-Banach, etc).

What I did so far was taking a converging sequence in A+B, and mark it as:
$x_k=a_k+\lambda_kv$, for $v$ the base of $B$.
I figured out that I could write the limit, $x$, as $x=P_Ax+P_{A^\perp}$ and do the same on $B$, and maybe work something from there.

I also thought that somehow it would be good to take advantage of the sequence $\lambda_k$ which is in $\mathbb{R}$ resp. $\mathbb{C}$. Maybe prove that it converges somehow..

Thanks so much

Comment: Do quotient spaces count as high theorems?

Comment: @DanielFischer: for me they do.

Comment: Pity. It's a nice argument that $A+B = \pi^{-1}(\pi(B))$, where $\pi \colon H \to H/A$ is the canonical projection, and as $\pi(B)$ is finite-dimensional and $H/A$ Hausdorff, $\pi(B)$ is closed.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I hope it is, yet I'll be studying this kind of stuff only in a simester or two, so I couldn't quite understand it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $B\subset A$, there is nothing to prove, so assume $B\not\subset A$, and let $b$ such that $B=\mathrm{span}\{b\}$. Of course, $b\not\in A$, and since $A$ is *closed*, $d(b,A)$ is positive, where $d$ is the metric induced by the norm. Without loss of generality, $d(b,A)=1$, and then for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in A$, $$\|tb+a\|\geq d(tb,A)=|t|.$$

Now let $(x_n)\subset A+B$ be a converging sequence. Write for every $n$ $\;x_n=t_n b+a_n$, where $t_n\in\mathbb{R},a_n\in A$, and it follows from the above paragraph that $(t_n)$ is a converging sequence. It follows then that so is $(a_n)$ and practically we're done.

Note that we didn't use the inner product, so all the above is true for Banach spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I could not understand why the inequallity implies that $(t_n)$ converges. I understand that $||x_n||>|t_n|$, but that would only imply the convergence if the limit of $x_n$ would be 0. as i try to insert the limit, say $x$ into this inequallity I lost everything since $x$ doesn't have to be at $A$.
That's actually, in some verse, what was holding me before.

Comment: A converging sequence is Cauchy, and $\|t_nb+a_n-(t_mb+a_m)\|=\|(t_n-t_m)b+(a_n-a_m)\|\geq|t_n-t_m|$. Hence the sequence $(t_n)$ is also Cauchy, and thus converging.

Comment: Now I feel dumb. for real. But I guess that it is called learning.. Thanks Amitai, you helped a lot.

Comment: Pleasure. And yeah, this is learning... (I know what you're talking about)

Comment: You don't even need to assume it is a Banach space. It holds in every normed space.