# If $Y$ is a closed subspace and $Z$ has finite dimension, then the set $Y+Z$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

So, we consider a Normed space $X$ and two subspaces $Y,Z$. If $Y$ is a closed subspace and $Z$ has finite dimension, then we need to prove that the set $Y+Z$ is closed. 
I've tried considering a sequence in $Y+Z$ that converges to a $x \in X$ and proving that $x \in Y+Z$, with no luck.
I should mention that, in my class we haven't done operators yet.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By induction, you only need to consider the case where $Z$ has dimension 1.

Comment: As @Kapil wrote, by induction it is enough to consider $Z$ to have dimension 1. Then, look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012395/a-sum-of-a-closed-subspace-and-a-closed-one-dimensional-space-is-closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Z'$ be a subspace of $Z$ such that $Z=Z'\oplus (Z\cap Y)$.

Then evidently $Z'$ is finite dimensional and
$Z+Y = Z'+Y$.  Moreover $Z'\cap Y=\{0\}$.

Therefore, upon replacing $Z$ by $Z'$, we may assume WLOG that $Z\cap Y=\{0\}$.

This said,  let $S_Z$ be the unit sphere of $Z$,  namely
$$
  S_Z= \{z\in Z:\Vert z\Vert =1\}.
  $$
Since $Z$ is finite dimensional, we have that $S_Z$ is compact, so
$$
  d:= \inf\{\|z-y\|: z\in S_Z, \ y\in Y\} >0.
  $$
Given any $y\in Y$ and any nonzero $z\in  Z$, notice that
$$
  \|y-z\| = \|z\|\Big\|\frac y{\|z\|}-\frac z{\|z\|}\Big\| \geq d\|z\|,
  $$
so
$$
  \|z\|\leq \frac 1d \|y-z\|,
  $$
even if $z=0$.
If follows that if $\{y_n+z_n\}_n$ is a sequence in $Y+Z$, converging to some $x$ in $X$, then
$$
  \|z_n-z_m\|\leq  \frac 1 d \|y_m-y_n - (z_n-z_m) \| \leq   \frac 1 d \|(y_m+z_m)-(y_n+z_n)\|,
  $$
and we see that $\{z_n\}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Z$.  From this one can prove that
$$
  \lim_{n\to \infty }y_n =   \lim_{n\to \infty }y_n +z_n -z_n = x -\lim_{n\to \infty }z_n \in  Y,
  $$
so
$$
  x=\lim_{n\to \infty }y_n +\lim_{n\to \infty }z_n \in  X+Y.
  $$

Comment: How do I instantly see that $S_Z$ is  indeed compact?

Comment: $S_Z$  is closed and bounded.  Moreover, all finite dimensional spaces are isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: In a metric space closed and  boundedness isn't enough to declare a set compact.  What does it mean by: isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$? How do I show that?

Comment: This is a standard result in Functional Analysis.  See e.g. Theorem III.3.1 in Conway's "A Course in Functional Analysis".

Comment: How can all FINITE dimensional spaces be similar to $\mathbb{R}^\infty$? $n$ can be $\infty$, right? Dimensions can be infinite.

Comment: What I mean is that any finite dimensional normed space $Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, where $n$ is the dimension of $Z$.

Comment: shouldn't $X$ and $Y$ be disjoint in order to have $d>0$?

Comment: @J.Spil, I guess you mean $Z$ and $Y$, right?  If so then, yes, you are 100% correct.  I have edited to correct for my mistake.  The fix didn't change much in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another simple answer: Let $Z= <e_1 , e_2, \dots , e_n>$. Consider the natural projection $\pi \colon X \to X/Y$. Note that
$$ \pi (Z) = <π(e_1),\pi(e_2), \dots , \pi(e_n) >,$$
since $\pi$ is linear. Hence, $\pi (Z)$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $ X/Y$ and thus closed. Notice that $ \pi^{-1} (\pi (Z)) =Y+Z$ which is closed since $\pi$ is continuous.